# How to make download bar?(QML QT)

Tags: qt, qml

This is how it should look like

Sorry but I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.

[image: download bars are depend on percentages]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QML [ProgressBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-progressbar.html) and bind the download progress to the `value` property. [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-progressbar) you can find more information about how to style the ProgressBar to fit your needs.

The `Timer` is just used to simulate the download progress. As @Ľubomír Carik mentioned you should connect the [QNetworkReply::downloadProgress()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qnetworkreply.html#downloadProgress) from your backend to the `value` of the `ProgressBar`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes

Window {
    id: root
    width: 320
    height: 100
    visible: true
    color: "#232323"

    component CustomProgressBar : ProgressBar {
        id: control
        value: 0.5

        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 20
            color: "#4c4c4c"
            radius: 8
        }

        contentItem: Item {
            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 20

            Rectangle {
                width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
                height: parent.height
                radius: 8
                color: "#c4a469"
            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 8

        Shape {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            width: 16
            height: 16

            layer.enabled: true
            layer.smooth: true
            layer.samples: 4

            ShapePath {
                strokeColor: "#c4a469"
                strokeWidth: 1
                fillColor: "transparent"
                PathSvg { path: "M.5 9.9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2.5a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2.5a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z" }
                PathSvg { path: "M7.646 11.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 10.293V1.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v8.793L5.354 8.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l3 3z" }
            }
        }

        CustomProgressBar { id: progressBar }

        Text {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            width: 30
            color: "white"
            text: Math.trunc(progressBar.value * 100) + "%"
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 100
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            if (progressBar.value < 1)
                progressBar.value += 0.01
            else
                progressBar.value = 0
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visual part can be handled as explained by @iam_peter.

Investigate header in [QNetworkReply](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qnetworkreply.html) to calculate value/percentage. Many servers return the size of data that will be sent (not all).

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient information to do this in `QML` alone. I checked the `XMLHttpRequest`, but the `onprogress` signal doesn't seem to fire. So there doesn't appear to be a way with that component.

Alternatively, you can implement your own with `QNetworkAccessManager`, `QNetworkRequest` and watch for the events in `QNetworkReply`. This was hinted by @Ľubomír-carik.

If you're uploading and downloading, then there are two signals of interest:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkreply.html#uploadProgress
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkreply.html#downloadProgress

It will be up to you to combine the results from these signals, e.g. you can assume 50% of the time is spent in uploading your payload and 50% of the time is spent in downloading your response.

It will be up to you how to calculate a single `progress` by combining the information above. Then you can feed it into a progress bar.

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-progressbar.html#value-prop

However, as @@Ľubomír-carik indicated not all requests are required to populate `Content-Length` for which how the downloadProgress is given. If `Content-Length` is not available, the information from downloadProgress is equivalent to non-determinate. So, you could either (1) leave the download progress stuck at 50% and jump to 100% when it's complete or (2) have an animation during the indeterminate download phase.

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-progressbar.html#indeterminate-prop